# How can i loop webm videos without delay?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, video, webm

**Hi all**, i want to run a webm-video in browser from desktop (from pc). Now i have looped the webm with this .js-file that i found:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Webm Looper
// @namespace   com.whatisthisimnotgoodwithcomputers.webmlooper
// @author      WhatIsThisImNotGoodWithComputers
// @description A userscript which automatically enables looping on Webm videos in your browser.
// @include       *.webm
// @run-at      document-start
// @version     1.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var vids = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
for (i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) 
 vids[i].setAttribute("loop", "true");
```

in Greasemonkey. It works, but there is a small delay in the repeat/loop. It shall look like if i run a gif 
in browser. Now i have looked for a solution and have found something in the forum:

[Issue setting currentTime in HTML5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240088/issue-setting-currenttime-in-html5-video)

But it doesn't work in Greasemonkey. This is my code in Greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Loop
// @namespace   Loop
// @version     1
// @include *.webm
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var vids = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
vids.play();
vids.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
 this.currentTime = 5;
});
```

The webm stops after first run.

The javascript-setting shows that video.play(); is not a function and the same at addeventlistener.

Maybe you can help me with this problem. What can i improve? Do i have to install something other or change?

Unfortunately I'm only a newbie in the programming.

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: any reason not to use the `loop` attribute on the `<video>` tag itself?

Comment: The reason is the delay. there is a small delay if the video begins again with the loop attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is track the `currentTime` attribute (you can use the `timeupdate` event for that) and when it gets close to the end (the `duration` attribute) you can reset it back to the start

In the sample below it uses the `loadedmetadata` event to know when the duration is available for the script, and starts the video playing and attaches a listener to `timeupdate` that then tracks the `currentTime`

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Looper Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<video id="video" muted preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script>
video = document.getElementById("video")
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata",init)

function init() {
    video.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata",init)
    video.play()
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', 
        funcloop=function(){
            if (video.currentTime >= (video.duration - 1)) {
                video.currentTime = 1;
                video.play()
            }
        }, false);
    }
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Second version which demonstrates use of setInterval to control the loop. Allows for smaller test interval

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Looper Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<video id="video" muted preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script>
video = document.getElementById("video")
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata",init)

function init() {
    video.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata",init)
    video.play()
    t = setInterval(looper, 100);
}

function looper() {
    console.log(video.currentTime);
    if (video.currentTime >= (video.duration - 0.1)) {
        video.currentTime = 0.2;
        video.play()
    }
}

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it doesn't work. The code looks reasonable. :D I have copied the code in greasemonkey, greasemonkey is enabled and the right script is active. Do i have to activate something?

Comment: it does work in Chrome - see https://jsfiddle.net/ps3yuj7f/ - why are you trying to run this in Greasemonkey rather than saving it as a web page and opening it in a browser? If I do that it works in Firefox/Safari as well (for some reason they're not working in the Fiddle)

Comment: In the example the video is named explicit. Can i run this

Comment: In the example the video is named explicit. source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4 "                      Can i run this with any video or have to change the source everytime? Is it correct that the browser then only opens the video-file and not other things from the code. I want to see only the video in the browser. Sorry for the "beginner" questions. I hope you continue to help me. :D

Comment: How can i save this as web page, so that i only double click on video from desktop to open it and then it runs? I would be glad to get a reply again. :D

Comment: I'd go read this article - https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/ - and some basics on HTML/Javascript development. SO isn't really a 'training' site, it's more about answering specific questions

Comment: Thanks for the basics. But I don't understand the backgrounds. Maybe i'm thinking too complicated. But i don't know how it is working. i tried to paste a webm video (internet-video) in the fiddle. That doesn't work. Can you show me how did you do that with firefox and the save of the web page?

Comment: do you know how to create a basic webpage? Take the code I've got in the answer (I'll add the rest of the code to make it self-contained) and save it as (eg) `test.html` then open the file using Firefox

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code runs, but I have to adjust something. If the currenttime is too low the video jumps to the beginning, but the video stops. If the currenttime is 1, is it ok.

Comment: there are two things you can adjust, and it would depend on the length of the video... the test triggers when they are 1 second away from the duration, so you might want to vary that number (especially if the video is very short), and the line that sets currenttime to 1 goes back to the 1s mark, could make that 0 or 0.5 if you need.

Comment: Is it possible that the loop is depended from the video and audio codec? Maybe it is loading too slow because of the audio too? Is there a difference between timeupdate (works in s) and settimeout (works in ms)? I have read that timeupdate triggers only if we have a time of 0.25s.

Comment: yes, timeupdate isn't very granular, using a settimeout will give you more granularity. The audio and video will load together. How long is your video? If you want to make sure the whole thing has loaded then replace the `loadedmetadata` event with `canplaythrough` to ensure enough is buffered. See https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html for all events

Comment: The code is running, but i still have the delay. I played with time steps, but no succes. Now i have found this in the forum: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28829879/seamless-html5-video-loop/38836240#38836240)  I want to try this one. I have downloaded jquery. maybe you can help me again... but only you have enough patience with me. :D

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by delay? can you share the actual video (if it's a huge file then there will potentially be buffering issues). The other solution you linked to would also work, toggling between the two copies of the same video

Comment: I have checked my webm converter. (Premiere Pro) If i convert the video without the audio, the video runs seamlessly. But if i paste the audio-trace, it runs with the delay. It's strange. Now i wanted to try the "video copies"-code. Do i need jquery? I ask, because i don't know how i can connect jquery and the other code. Where i have to put the code for the video source and so on if i use jquery. Maybe you can help me again. ;)

Comment: suggest you ask a new question for help with a jQuery solution as that would be different to this. I suspect your video encoding may give you the same problem though. can you share that so we can see the problem