# gap in audio when playing looping WEBM video in browser

Tags: video, html5-video, webm

I have an animation with an audio track in WEBM format that I'm attempting to run as a seamless loop in the browser. To embed, I'm using the following HTML:

```
<video id="dp" width="560" height="420" controls="controls" loop>
  <source src="https://staging.hammys-exotic-brats.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/pd7.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

The animation itself is looping fine, however the audio track has a noticeable gap of silence that can consistently be heard right as it loops. Same results with it in .MOV format and embedded/streamed through YouTube as well as playing it on loop in Quicktime Player.

If I bring the original .MOV file into a video editing program and play 2 (or more) instances of the file back to back (to back to back....), it plays seamlessly, but I can't get it to happen for the loop.

In case it's of any consequence, I converted the MOV to WEBM using FFMPEG on Macos with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i pd7.mov -vf unpremultiply=inplace=1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0 -crf 31 -s 924x1008 pd7.webm
```

The original MOV was created with ToonBoom harmony.

I've seen a handful of similar questions asked around thee web but haven't come across anything in the way of a definitive solution.

Has anybody run into this and/or have any suggestions?

### EDIT

This is far from perfect and is more of a workaround than an answer to my actual question... AND I hoping (and still am) NOT to have to go this route, but I will if I have to. Here's a javascript solution compliments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931501/how-can-i-loop-webm-videos-without-delay) that listens for the end of the video and does the looping in place of having the player doing it.

```
<script>
video = document.getElementById("dp")
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata",init)

function init() {
    video.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata",init)
    video.play()
    video.addEventListener('timeupdate', 
        funcloop=function(){
            if (video.currentTime >= (video.duration - 1)) {
                video.currentTime = 1;
                video.play()
            }
        }, false);
    }
</script>
```

I'm still all ears if anyone has a solution that keeps the looping functionality in the player.